# Operation returned an invalid status code: 'NotFound'

Tags: azure, object-detection-api, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I actually trained the model of custom vision to detect vehicles and i want to detect them in real time, so i tried to run the sample app available in github https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-VideoFrameAnalysis , but i always get this error : Operation returned an invalid status code: 'NotFound', it says on the internet that i didnt specify the concerned iteration, but i didnt find where to do it in the sample app, they also suggested to set the iteration as default but i didn't find this option in custom vision configurations.

Comment: Okay @AnanthaRajuC i'm a beginner here,  what didn't you understand in this question ?

Comment: That sample app predates the Custom Vision API being generally available, so it won't work 'out of the box'.  Can you share the code that instantiates the API client and how you call the service using this client?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while working with WebApps in Azure. So I'm posting my findings here in case it helps someone.

I was trying to create an App Service Plan using `New-AzAppServicePlan` PowerShell (PS) commandlet which is part of `Az.Websites` module.

```
New-AzAppServicePlan  -Name $appServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup  -Location $location -Tier Free
```

In the end it turned out that I was missing enclosing single quote around the argument `Free` that I was passing for `-Tier` parameter. So below command worked.

```
New-AzAppServicePlan  -Name $appServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup  -Location $location -Tier 'Free'
```